# Find all entire functions $f$ such that $|f|$ is harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm trying to find all entire functions $f$ such that $|f|$ is harmonic. My attempt is as follows.

Because $f$ is entire, we may write $f(z) = f(x + iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ where $u$ and $v$ have continuous first-order partial derivatives and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Furthermore, $u$ and $v$ are harmonic. Now $|f| = \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$ so I thought maybe to look at $|f|^2$ first. Then,
$$(|f|^2)_{xx} = 2(u_x)^2 + 2(v_x)^2 + 2(u\cdot u_{xx} + v \cdot v_{xx})$$
and
$$(|f|^2)_{yy} = 2(u_y)^2 + 2(v_y)^2 + 2(u\cdot u_{yy} + v \cdot v_{yy}).$$
I need $(|f|^2)_{xx} + (|f|^2)_{yy} = 0$ in order for $|f|^2$ to be harmonic. So adding these equations and using that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic, I obtain
$$(u_x)^2 + (u_y)^2 + (v_x)^2 + (v_y)^2 = 0.$$
By the Cauchy-Riemann equations, I can simplify this to
$$(u_x)^2 + (v_x)^2 = 0.$$
I'm a little stuck on how to proceed from here. I want to somehow conclude $|f|^2$ is constant but I'm not sure how.

Comment: $u_x$ and $v_x$ are real numbers, so $u_x=v_x=0$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! To check my logic, I can conclude that $u_x = v_y = v_x = u_y = 0$ and this must imply that $|f|^2$ is constant. Therefore, $|f|$ must be constant and so by Liouville, $f$ is necessarily constant. Does this sound right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: It is no wrong by evaluating $\Delta(\sqrt{u^2+v^2})$ directly. saulspatz is right.

Comment: @NikosBagis So do the computations above for $|f|$ rather than $|f|^2$?

Comment: @Nina. Yes. It is more easy to work with $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$. I will write ananswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(z)=f(x+iy)=u+iv$. Then from analyticity of $f$:
$$
u_x=-v_y\textrm{ and }u_y=v_x.\tag 1
$$
Hence if $|f|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ (away from the zeros  of $f$), then
$$
|f|_x=\frac{u_x+v_x}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\Rightarrow |f|_{xx}=\frac{(u_{xx}+v_{xx})|f|-\frac{(u_x+v_x)^2}{|f|}}{|f|^2}\Rightarrow
$$
$$
|f|_{xx}=\frac{u_{xx}+v_{xx}}{|f|}-\frac{(u_x+v_x)^2}{|f|^3}.\tag 2
$$
In the same way
$$
|f|_{yy}=\frac{u_{yy}+v_{yy}}{|f|}-\frac{(u_y+v_y)^2}{|f|^3}.\tag 3
$$
Hence using $u_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$, $v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$ and equations (1), we get
$$
\Delta|f|=|f|_{xx}+|f|_{yy}=-\frac{1}{|f|^3}\left((u_x+u_y)^2+(u_y-u_x)^2\right)=-2|f|^{-3}\left((u_x)^2+(u_y)^2\right).\tag 4
$$
Hence
$$
\Delta|f|=0\textrm{ iff }(u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0)\textrm{ iff }f=const.\tag 5
$$
In case that $f(z)$ is zero in a set $A$, then $A$ will be discrete and from (5) constant in $\textbf{C}-A$. Hence $f(z)$ zero everywhere.

Comment: You must also show first that f has no zeros in order to justify the differentiation.

Comment: I add the corrections in my answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have demonstrated that constant functions are the only entire functions for which $|f|^2$ is harmonic.

Now let us investigate the case where $f$ is entire and $ |f|$ is harmonic. We can assume that $f$ is not identically zero.

It is surely possible to calculate $\Delta |f|$ directly, but one can simplify the work by showing first that $f$ has no zeros, so that $f=e^g$ for some entire function $g$: Assume that $f(z_0) = 0$, then
$$
 0 = |f(z_0)| = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(z_0+re^{it}| \, dt
$$
for all $r > 0$, which implies that $f$ is identically zero, in contrast to the assumption.

So we have $|f| =|e^g| = e^{\operatorname{Re} g} = e^v$ where $v =  \operatorname{Re} g$ is harmonic. Then
$$
 0 = \Delta |f| = \Delta(e^v) = e^v \left(v_{xx} + (v_x)^2 + v_{yy} +  (v_y)^2\right)
 = e^v \left( (v_x)^2 +  (v_y)^2\right)
$$
so that $v_x$ and $v_y$ are identically zero. It follows that $v$ is constant. Consequently, $|f|$ is constant, which implies that $f$ is constant.

Comment: How do we get the implication that $f$ is identically zero?

Comment: $ \int_0^{2\pi} |f(z_0+re^{it}| \, dt = 0$ implies that $f$ is zero on the circle with center $z_0$ and radius $r$, for all $r > 0$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I appreciate the alternate approach to this problem.